# Removing control ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, hex, character, ascii

```
function RemoveASCIIControlCharacters(xmlString) {
    var cleanXmlString = xmlString.replace(/VT/g,'');
    cleanXmlString = cleanXmlString.replace(/SUB/g, '');
    return cleanXmlString;
}
```

Please replace VT and SUB with real control character.

The removal of the VT control character works. However the removal of the SUB control character fails.

How do I filter out the SUB(0x1A) control character?

Answer (score 0):

Use \xY where Y is the hexadecimal character code, E.g. for both:

```
return cleanXmlString.replace(/[\x0b\x1a]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use octal character escape and range: `/[\0-\32]/g`